# Reading an excel file into python which is present at different network location

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code in jupyter noteboks which reads an excel file and creates a dataframe out of it. The catch in this problem is that the file is not present in same location but on a different network drive. Say, my Python runs in C drive but my excel file is present in M network drive.

I have tried pd.read_excel(r'path') command but it throws an error of-"no such file or directory"

Comment: Python has nothing to do with accessing the file, if you have a path for excel which is accessible then python can read that file too.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you are looking for , and the syntax for jupyter notebooks is a little different, but try changing the path before reading the file?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.chdir(r"M:\path")
df = pd.read_excel('filename')
```